# Is it possible to upload data in different languages into the firebase by user

Tags: java, android, firebase

In my android app, when a user enters data, it has to upload to the database and the data has to be translated into different languages. So, that the user can access the data in his/her desired language. Is it possible? If possible please tell me. If not possible, any alternatives or any ideas will be upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a trigger in the database, so that when the record is created, a function is run to perform the translation and save the translated text alongside the original data.  This is similar to the pattern described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#perform_database_sanitization_and_maintenance), more information about triggers in the Cloud Firestore db [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) - looks as though there are similar triggers for Realtime Database too.

Comment: If OP is using Firestore, there is even an official Extension that handles precisely this scenario: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-translate-text